# Oracle group by spatial intersect?

Tags: oracle, group-by, intersect, oracle-spatial

I have a large amount of workplace (+/- 200 000) over an area of 160 sq km and spread in time over about 20 years.

What I would like to obtain for each workplace is: 
ID 
IDs of the intersecting worplaces 
Min_Start_Date of all the spatial intersecting workplaces 
Max_Start_Date of all the spatially intersecting workplaces

So basically I need the equivalent of 'group by intersection', does anyone know how to tackle this?

Workplaces
ID integer 
StartDate Date 
EndDate Date

Workplaces_GIS : 
ID Integer 
SHAPE SDOgeometru

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on 11g R2 or greater, you could use this query:

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        listagg(b.ID, ',') within group (order by b.ID) as Intersect_ids,
        min(b.StartDate) as Min_Start_Date,
        max(b.EndDate) as Max_Start_Date
    FROM workplaces a, workplaces b
        WHERE a.ID != b.ID
        AND sdo_relate(a.geom, b.geom, 'mask = anyinteract') = 'TRUE'
        GROUP BY a.ID;
```